# How do I rename a table via command line

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the Google SDK bq command. How do I change the name of a table? I'm not seeing this at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to copy to a new table and delete the original.

```
$ bq cp dataset.old_table dataset.new_table
$ bq rm -f -t dataset.old_table
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way just rename table
What you can do is COPY table to a new table with desired name (copy is free of charge) and then delete original table

The only drawback I see with this is that if you have long term stored data - I think you will lose storage discount (50%) for that data